# C#: Can't cast a string to Generic T when T is "String"?

Tags: c#, generics

I have  the following method which attempts to parse a string into a type T  when T provides a parse(string) method:

```
public static bool ParseToType<T>(string s, out T parsedValue)
    {
         if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
            parsedValue =  (T) s;  //doesn't compile.
            return true;

        }
        if (!IsParseable(typeof(T)))
        {
            parsedValue = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        var meth = typeof(T).GetRuntimeMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(String) });
        try
        {
            parsedValue = (T)meth.Invoke(typeof(T), new String[] { s });
        }
        catch (  Exception e) {
            parsedValue = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However I need to deal with the special case when the type of T is also string.  String doesnt provide a "parse" method, so I would just like to return the string supplied (s).

However I can't figure out how to cast s to T when T itself is string.

Comment: `parsedValue =  s;` :)

Comment: Would be nice if that worked.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. Didn't notice it is generic type.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  `parsedValue = (T) (object) s;`